# How to Create Contact QR code in iphone

Tags: iphone, contacts, qr-code

I am working for Qr generator application and for that I have nice kyupay Library.

In that Library I need to pass string value and it returns QR Image.

It's working nice for text,Email and etc...

But Now i wants to create QR Image for Contact and Event And i don't know how to do this.

so My problem is  what should be the logic for that ????

please suggest me or if you have code for that then please Share it.

Comment: I need to pass string like this     BEGIN:VCARD
N;CHARSET=utf-8:babi;sarafaraz;;;
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:sarafaraz babi
TITLE;CHARSET=utf-8:Software Developer
TEL;WORK:1234567489
TEL;CELL:12345875
EMAIL;INTERNET;WORK;CHARSET=utf-8:safi@logisticinfotech.com
ADR;WORK;CHARSET=utf-8:;;;Rajkot;Guarat;;India
VERSION:2.1
END:VCARD

Comment: I am getting this string from scanning contact qr code..

Comment: Is something like this any help? http://snapmyinfo.com/blog/how-to-create-a-business-card-qr-code/

Comment: hi agrothe, Thanks for link but this link gives me the qr image and it's string and i wants how to generate this type of string  from the contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for respond me on my question.

I finally creates a function that returns contact Qr code string.

It's easy but too long.

we have to check for data inputs from user and append sting as per data and create string.

I am Posting my code so it may help others and save theirs time.

```
-(NSString *)GenerateStringForContact{

    NSString *str = @"";
    NSMutableArray *arr1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0 ; i<[arrayAttributeName count]; i++) {

        if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"First Name"]) {
            if ([strContactType isEqualToString:@"ContactMecard"]) {
             [arr1 addObject:@"N:"];
            }else{
             [arr1 addObject:@"FN:"];   
            }
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Last Name"]) {
//            [arr1 addObject:@"N:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Phone"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"TEL:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Email"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"EMAIL:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"URL"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"URL:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Nickname"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"NICKNAME:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Title"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"TITLE:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Organization"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"ORG:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Birthday"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"BDAY:"];
        }else if ([[arrayAttributeName objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Note"]) {
            [arr1 addObject:@"NOTE:"];
        }

    }

    NSMutableArray *contDetail = arrayAttributeValue;

    if ([strContactType isEqualToString:@"ContactMecard"]) {
        str = @"MECARD:";
//         arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"N:",@"TEL:",@"EMAIL:",@"URL:",@"NOTE:",@"NICKNAME:",@"BDAY:",@"ADR:",nil];

    }else{

       str = @"BEGIN:VCARD";
//       arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"N:",@"TEL:",@"EMAIL:",@"URL:",@"NOTE:",@"NICKNAME:",@"BDAY:",@"ADR:",@"TITLE:",@"ORG:",nil];
    }

    BOOL count = TRUE;
    for (int i =0; i <[contDetail count]; i++) {

        if (![[contDetail objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]) {

            NSString *tmp2 =@"";

            if (i == 0 || i == 1) {
                if (count) {


                    if ([strContactType isEqualToString:@"ContactMecard"]) {

                        tmp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[contDetail objectAtIndex:0],[contDetail objectAtIndex:1]];

                        NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i],tmp2];

                    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;%@",str,tmp];

                    }else{
                        tmp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[contDetail objectAtIndex:0],[contDetail objectAtIndex:1]];

                        NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i],tmp2];

                        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",str,tmp];
                    }

                    count = FALSE;
                }

            }else{

                tmp2 = [contDetail objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:i-1],tmp2];

                if ([strContactType isEqualToString:@"ContactMecard"]) {

                    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;%@",str,tmp];

                }else{
                    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",str,tmp];
                }


            }

        }
    }

    if (![strContactType isEqualToString:@"ContactMecard"]) {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nEND:VCARD",str];


    }
    NSLog(@"here string for generate code %@",str);    

    return str;
}
```

Thanks....

Comment: Do anyone have any idea how to do this in swift?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Contact QR code at this site: http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/ it provides for you the string it uses to create the QR Code. Maybe you can use this as inspiration?

Comment: hello Eli,..thanks for the link but I Think i need to check for every data into if..else loop and then create string like that...